# Shipping charges depending on price range

Tags: magento-1, shipping, free-shipping, table-rates, delivery

Below charges should set automatically:

1)if you buy products within $0 to $50 price = $6.00 freight charges

2)if you buy products within  $51 to $250 price = $12.00 freight charges

3)over $251.00 = FREE

How to set up them?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Comment: hi boss, you done a great job, thanks a lot again , again and again.... worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify the shipping Rates according to the Price in the Shopping Cart, then you can use the default Table Rates options.

System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > Table Rates

You have to choose Price Vs Destination in condition option.

Please refer a link for the above for the same.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, i will check your link.

Comment: I am not getting it , You want to implement the shipping price Rate according to the price in shopping cart . And its happening then what is the problem ??

Comment: hi , now i got it, before i was confused. thanks a lot, i am working as like  your link.

Comment: Hi , If you find my answer and link usefull , Please vote for my answer . It may help others too. Thanks.

Comment: ya, sure, please wait for some time, i am still working on that.

Comment: hi @Rahul, you done a great job, thanks a lot, worked perfectly fine.